# Talend tFileInputDelimited row count

Tags: talend, rowcount, data-integration

I want row count which is mentioned in the image, to be used in my expression. How can I access it?

Image is here:

[image: image is here]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://help.talend.com/reader/g8zdjVE7fWNUh3u4ztO6Dw/Kbz5WfMuxJ_iK6mJi4Fivg), there are several available variables. It depends on the place where you want to use the variable if it is already filled. This is from the aforementioned page:

> NB_LINE: the number of rows processed. This is an After variable and it returns an integer.

So in your case this would be

```
((Integer) globalMap.get("tFileInputDelimited_2_NB_LINE"))
```

Talend also offers those variables in component input fields if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.